# How to sort column fields and get its total

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

[image: SharePoint List Screenshot]

Dear SharePoint Experts,

I would like to ask for tech support regarding on the screenshot that I attached.
As you can see from the image, I have a My Requests, All Items, My Balance views, in My Requests are the details that I made. But what I want to have in My Balance View is to sort out and calculate some values.
So here it should goes (but I have no idea how should be the calculated script should be):
If Request Type = Business Leave, and I only need to get the Approved one from the LeaveApprovalProcess Column, then it should Total the Number of Days/Hours from the Total Leave Column... I don't need to add the Rejected one, only the Approved one...

Then with that formula, it will be the same with the other Request Type.

Thank you and looking forward to hear soon...

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that:

- Filters on Request Type = Business Leave AND LeaveApprovalProcess = Approved
- Totals on a Number column.

Your example probably does not have a Number column. What is the data type for the Total Leave column? Text? It would need to be a Number type. Can you represent this data as Hours (48 for two days) or Days (2.5 for 60 hours)?  What is your definition of "day"? 8 hours or 24 hours?

Comment: Hi there Mr. Smith! Thanks for your kind response... I don't have a Number column yet on it, ok, will add another column and set it as "Number". For the data type of Total Leave column, it's Date and Time, however I changed it already to Number. And here's the formula for the Total Leave column

Comment: =DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]-(MOD([Start Date],1)>MOD([End Date],1)),"d")&" days, "&TEXT(MOD([End Date]-[Start Date],1),"hh ""hrs, ""mm "" mins""")

Comment: Re: Filters on Request Type = Business Leave AND LeaveApprovalProcess = Approved, I filtered on Request Type = Business Leave BUT couldn't find the LeaveApprovalProcess on the next selection... The Type of this column "LeaveApprovalProcess" is Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink column cannot be filtered in a view. This is by design. You need to use nother column type to achieve this.

Comment: Kindly advise what column to add and what type. And for that column "LeaveApprovalProcess", what should be the Data Type of it? Hope to hear from you again...

Comment: You could change the column "LeaveApprovalProcess" to the type Single line of text.